# Select records by month in where clause

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My query to get data by month

```
$this->db->select('vehicle_make_and_model');
$this->db->join('tukai_drivers','tukai_drivers.driver_id=reqn_challans.dc_driver_id','left');
$this->db->where('dc_challan_date','MONTH(2)');
$this->db->order_by('dc_challan_id','desc');
$result=$this->db->get('reqn_challans')->result();
```

I am trying it via codeignitor like this

```
$this->db->where('dc_challan_date','MONTH(2)');
```

It did not work? What is wrong

Storing date like this

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0424q72ne5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to update your where condition from

```
$this->db->where('dc_challan_date','MONTH(2)');
```

to

```
$this->db->where('MONTH(dc_challan_date)','2');
```

The actual function is like `MONTH(date)` so here you have `MONTH(dc_challan_date)` which is your column name

Comment: While this answer may correct the syntax, it overlooks the problem of using a function on the data in a where clause. Research the term "sargable".

Answer (score 1):

In SQL databases you should **NOT** apply functions to data to suit the where clause so that you maximize the benefit of indexes (i.e. get better performance). For example, instead of using MONTH(dc_challan_date) you can achieve getting a month of data using the >= with < such as the following SQL:

```
select * from table
where dc_challan_date >= '2015-02-01'
and dc_challan_date < '2015-03-01'
```

The database optimizer can use an index on column dc_challan_date in that query. The example uses "[sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) predicates".