# Codeigniter: Fetch the value from an option in the dropdown list and check SQL condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having an issue fetching the values from a dropdown list to check a condition with the mysql query. It is using codeigniter. Let me post the code I have included below:

**VIEW:**

```
<select name="month" id="month">
        <option>Select Month</option>
        <option value="01">January</option>
        <option value="02">February</option>
        <option value="03">March</option>
        <option value="04">April</option>
        <option value="05">May</option>
        <option value="06">June</option>
        <option value="07">July</option>
        <option value="08">August</option>
        <option value="09">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
```

The above values should be equal to the month in the date column of the table. I will post my model below:

**MODEL:**

```
$month = $this->input->post('month');
    $this->datatables->select('order_no,order_date,naturescrm_customers.name,total,naturescrm_users.username,naturescrm_order.id,
        naturescrm_order_status.status_name')
        ->unset_column('naturescrm_order.id')
        ->add_column('Actions', btn_edit('agent/order/edit/' . '$1').' '.get_view('$1','agent/order/view/') ,'naturescrm_order.id')
        ->from($this->_table_name)
        ->join("naturescrm_customers","naturescrm_customers.id=naturescrm_order.customer_id","left")
        ->join("naturescrm_order_status","naturescrm_order_status.status_id=naturescrm_order.order_status","left")
        ->join("naturescrm_users","naturescrm_users.id=naturescrm_order.user_id","left")
        ->where("DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%m') = $month");
        $this->db->order_by("order_date","desc");
```

There is my code in the model and in the view, So when I Select a month in the dropdown, the values being fetched in the database should reflect based on the month. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select records by month in where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277333/select-records-by-month-in-where-clause)

Comment: Hi Uchicha, it works when I hardcode the number, But when I use a variable `$months` it doesn't.

Comment: Are you getting any error

Comment: Nope, but when I do change the month in the dropdown, nothing happens. Nothing loads in the first place like it used to

Comment: Check the network tab / console you might be getting an error

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) --> this is the error I am getting on a function in the controller called list_order.

Comment: ->where("DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%m') ", "$month");

Comment: Hey Praveen, thanks for the reply, that did remove the spinning gear in the datatables, but when I change the month, I still don't retrieve the data

Comment: No Praveen, that did not help. using `(int)` did though.